# Where is standard Unit tests triggered in Android Studio App project?

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, android-testing

In a Android Studio app project, some Unit tests were added. But while building them manually (within Android Studio) or externally (in a continuous integration system) where these tests can be triggered?

I was assume, that these tests are triggered automatically, on each build. **Where would I set e.g. in gradle file to trigger these Unit Tests on each build and to fail this build, if any Unit tests fails?**

Comment: What do you mean where can be triggered? You can run them in the Android studio or via gradle in command line. Gradle files are for building the project, they do not define what happens.

Comment: A task "checkTest" might have been added to gradle files and called somewhere in the gradle files..

Comment: You don't run in it the Gradle files, you use gradle to run that task :-). That's basically all that building an app is. e.g. `gradlew checkTest`